# Map constructor with comparator

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

```
class cmp{  // simple comparison function
public:
    bool operator()(const int x,const int y)
    { return x > y; }
};
```

When I call any stl algorithms like std::sort with an object of compare , it works fine.

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp());
```

But for stl containers this is not similar.

```
std::map<int, int> mp(cmp()); // Not working
std::map< int, int, cmp> mp;  // Works fine.
```

Also, in case of lambda expression,

```
auto lamda = [](cont int x, const int y)
{ return x > y; };

std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> mp(lamda); //Works
std::map<int, int > mp(lambda); // not working
```

Can anyone explain the difference ?

Comment: `std::map<int, int>` is a shorthand for `std::map<int, int, std::lest<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int>>>`. Which is to say, it expects `std::lest<int>` as a comparator, and not `cmp` or any other type. If you want a map with a different comparator, you must specify it as a template parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp());
```

because function templates can deduce their template arguments from the provided arguments.  For stl containers this does not work because you're not calling a template function, but declaring a specialization of a class template.

```
std::map<int, int> mp(cmp()); // Not working
std::map< int, int, cmp> mp; // Works fine.
```

For classes, if you provide any template parameters explicitly, you must provide them all (and for pre-c++17 you must provide them period.)  The `Compare` template argument (3rd arg) defaults to `std::less<Key>` unless you tell it otherwise, as your example demonstrates.

This is just how c++ is.  There's nothing you're doing wrong, but wanting to omit that parameter is not going to work.

Your lambda example has an identical explanation.

C++17 added Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD) which works only if you allow it to deduce (or default) *all* the template parameters.  You cannot explicitly provide any, or CTAD is disabled.  With CTAD it is possible, but not advisable.
For example, you can declare a map like this:

```
std::map m{{std::pair{0, 0}}, std::greater<>{}};
```

But 1) this is rather ugly and is probably worse solution than the problem it's trying to solve, and 2) it creates the map with an initial element in it.  The only other constructor that might work is if you already have an existing map with the correct key/value types, and provide an empty range of iterators into it to your constructor to create an empty object copy.

```
// also possible, assuming you have m1, you can use an 
// empty range (from end to end, for example)
std::map<int, int> m1;

// CTAD works here but will make people blink when they see it
std::map m2{end(m1), end(m1),  std::greater<>{}};
```

But this is kind of a contrived situation.  If you don't already have m1, then it's not really a solution.  To be clear, I'm not advising this, only mentioning it for completeness.

In short, unless you are wanting to do gymnastics and create an atrocity of code, you should just provide the type of the comparison as a template argument to containers.

Comment: Follow up question: In case of function object, we don't need to pass the object , only the type is sufficient `std::map< int, int, cmp> mp; ` . But in case of lambda expression we need to pass the lambda `std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> mp(lamda);` . I believe both will evoke this constructor `explicit map (const key_compare& comp,const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());` and here we need the comp object. So, how the first case is working ?

Comment: @AnirbanSaha A function object has associated behavior in the overloaded operator().  But when you declare your comparator as `bool(*)(int, int)`, your (stateless) lambda is converted into a _function pointer_.  The signature of the function alone is not enough for the compiler to invoke the function, it needs an actual function for the pointer to point to.  But Function Objects can be default constructed, and the operator() is associated with the type, so it knows the _behavior_ that goes along with it, not just what it _looks like_.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you were attempting to use here is:

```cpp
explicit map( const Compare& comp, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

However, the fact that it was declared `explicit` means it cannot deduce the temp of `Compare`, and you have to manually put the type of your comparator when you initiate it.

---

Side note:
I believe for your functor, it need to be a `const` member function.

Comment: I don't think `explicit` has anything to do with template argument deduction? It didn't happen at least because OP manually provided template params.